# How do I use hasNext properly?

Tags: java

Why does the hasNext line return an error when I try to compile this?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "woodchuck.txt" ));

    HashMap<String, Integer> histoMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    String word;
    while((infile.hasNext()) !=null)
    {

        if(histoMap.get(word)==null)
            histoMap.put(word,1);
        else
            histoMap.put(word, histoMap.get(word)+1);
    }
    infile.close();
    System.out.print(histoMap);
}
```

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: I think you're trying to use a Scanner...? But you're using the BufferedReader wrong for sure.

Answer (score 4):

`BufferedReader` doesn't provide a method `hasNext()`. Instead `readLine()` simply returns `null` as soon as the end of the file is reached. And since you don't read anything, your code contains an endlessloop.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to `readLine()` and adding an assignment to `word` are enough to get it outputting results:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        try(BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("woodchuck.txt"))) 
        {
            HashMap<String, Integer> histoMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

            String word;
            while((word = infile.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(histoMap.get(word) == null)
                    histoMap.put(word,1);
                else
                    histoMap.put(word, histoMap.get(word)+1);
            }
            System.out.print(histoMap);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            String pwd = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\";
            FileNotFoundException e2 = new FileNotFoundException(pwd + e.getMessage());
            e2.initCause(e);
            throw e2;
        } 
    }
}
```

Adding the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) will ensure `infile` will be closed even if an exception is thrown.

I added the working directory thing because it's so handy to know exactly where it's not finding the file.  Useful when hard coding file names that aren't fully qualified paths.